# Doing a simple textadventure with php

Tags: php, html, function

Week ago I finished my code for a text adventure using functions `fgets(STDIN)` which is working through command line. Now I need to do the same this using html(Internetbrowser)  and here comes the problem. I don't know how I should replace this:

```
$choose=0;

while($choose!=1 && $choose!=2 && $choose!=3)
{
    $choose =fgets(STDIN);

    if ($choose==1)
    {
        print "..."
    }
```

into this:

```
<html>    
<head>
    <center> <b> <font size="12"> RPG Spiel </font> </b> </center>
</head>

<form method="POST" action="Spiel.php">
    <label> Wählen :
        <button type="submit" name="submit">1</button> 
        <button type="submit" name="submit2">2</button> 
        <button type="submit" name="submit3">3</button> 
    </label>
    </select>        
</form>

<?php
    $value1=$_POST['submit'];
    $value2=$_POST['submit2'];

    function display()
    {
        echo "..."

        if(isset($value1))
        {   
            echo "Option 1";
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['2']))
        {
            echo "Option 2";
        }
    }
?>
```

Could you please tell me which method could help me with it? 
Is it even possible?

Comment: You might enjoy MUDs. Check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're close, there are just a few problems:

1. `function display()` - You are using `$value1` in your function, but are not passing it as a parameter (`function display($value1)`), so it will *never* be set. (see [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).)
2. `if (isset($value1))` - If you *do* pass `$value1` as a parameter, it will *always* be set, unless you pass a `null` value.
3. You never call your `display()` function.

I'd recommend just using the `$_POST` values directly in your function, like this:

```
function display()
{
    echo "...";

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo "Option 1";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['submit2']))
    {
        echo "Option 2";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['submit3']))
    {
        echo "Option 3";
    }
}
```

And then don't forget to call the function.

```
display();
```

As far as the while loop in your console app that waits for input, the HTTP version already kind of works like that automatically. PHP will send the form to the browser and the user will see that form until they submit it.

Comment: Thank for advice it really helped me, but now i have just one last question, how do i go to another function without having the output from the last function ?

Comment: @sinedo I think I know what you're asking, but I'm not completely sure. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @DontPanic there you go(making sure you get the notification, im new here)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function display()
    {
         echo "You are here";

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            echo "Option 1";

        } elseif (isset($_POST['submit2']))
        {

            display2();

        }


    }


    function display2()
    {
        echo "Now you are there";

}

display();
```

after choosing the "submit2" option the output should look like this : "Now you are there" and not "You are hereNow you are there".